# Angular typecast $event

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to apply fix the issues by enabling the strict mode and one of the issue I faced that I don't have a clean answer for that is when $event is unknown

```
<div
     echarts
     (chartInit)="onChartInit($event)"
     (chartLegendSelectChanged)="onChartLegendSelectChanged($event)"
     (chartRendered)="onChartRender($event)"
></div>
```

here I have 3 methods that is returning unknown,

[image]

but refering to the document for example in `onChartLegendSelectChanged` I know that it return a `LegendOption`

so I define the method like this:

```
onChartLegendSelectChanged($event: LegendOption) {
    //logic when chart legend selected
}
```

while this is correct and typescript is happy about it, angular isn't happy with it and expect the method definition be type of `unknown`

while I can change the function argument to `unknown` and inside the function I cast the type to the desired type, but it's very ugly.

so is there anyway to cast the $event to a type inside the template? i saw other solution use pipe, but you can't use pipe inside a method call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use $any() function in template.

In your case:
(chartLegendSelectChanged)="onChartLegendSelectChanged($any($event))"

it's basically declare it as any type :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you have to provide a type for the `@Output`:

```
  @Output() chartLegendSelectChanged = new EventEmitter<LegendOption>();
```

This way you can maintain type safety (which isn't the case with $any).

Comment: that comes from a third party lib, there is nothing I can do